# Obtener "unixtime" hora unix en Java (Android)

Tags: java, php, android

La función [time() en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.time.php) se obtiene el número de segundos desde la Época Unix (1 de Enero de 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Ejemplo: 1465491771

En java como se puede obtener el valor equivalente a Unix Time?

Comment: `System#currentTimeMillis` o `new java.util.Date().getTime()`, devolverían exactamente lo mismo: el tiempo actual en milisegundos. Lo divides entre 1000 para convertirlo a segundos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unix Time](https://currentmillis.com/tutorials/system-currentTimeMillis.html) en **Segundos**:

```
  long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long unixTimeSegs = millis / 1000;
```

una versión más corta de obtener el valor:

```
  long unixTimeSegs = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

[Unix Time](https://currentmillis.com/tutorials/system-currentTimeMillis.html) en **MiliSegundos**:

```
long unixTimeMSegs = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

En PHP

```
$t=time();
```

En Android (Java)

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;  // Esto por que unixtime esta en segundos
```

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() te devuelve un resultado en milisegundos por ello uso la division

Comment: Oh, error mío. No había leido bien esa frase. Borrando comentarios.